# Using boost::asio and native socket calls within same process

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

Are there any known issues in using Boost::asio and native calls like accept() (both TCP sockets) within same process (different threads). I am on Debian and using C++ language.
My observation is that accept() behaves inconsistently.

On a particular instance of running the process,
Clients are able to connect smoothly. Any number of clients connect smoothly.

On another instance of running the process, accept call just fails saying "Invalid argument" when a client connects. Such an error is supposed to come when the socket is not properly configured as listening socket. Once this error, same error comes for all the clients trying to connect. Only workaround is to run the process again and hope that next time it works fine.

More observations:-
- When some more descriptors are opened for some files, problem tends to go away
- If I remove the boost::asio code, accept works absolutely fine

Limitations:
Cannot share my code

Comment: "`EINVAL`: Socket is not listening for connections, or addrlen is invalid (e.g., is negative)."  Consider using `strace` to isolate the cause of the failure.  This will make finding out the limitations between `asio` and native calls easier.

Comment: You need to provide some more details on how `boost::asio` and native socket are related in your code. Are you trying to bind to the same address from both?

Comment: As I mentioned, both are for different functionality in different threads. In the main thread, I am initializing the boost::io_service  as client counterpart to some server and the listening socket for accepting connections. It's the same process, same address(?). Frankly, I am not much familiar with boost::asio. Does it need/reserve some range of descriptors. I cannot change the code to have same calls for both things, need to use them together.

Comment: There's no problem to mix asio and native calls. The issue is somewhere in your program logic flow.

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues using Boost.Asio with system calls such as `accept()`, I've done it in several projects without problems. Based on your description, it sounds like undefined behavior to me. I would guess you are leaking descriptors, double `close()`-ing descriptors, or not checking return codes where appropriate. If you are unable to post code, use a tool like valgrind to aid your debugging efforts.

Answer (score 0):

I spawned two different threads. No problem after that.